# Shall I call CreateQueue whenever I need to send a message to Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I somehow see this phrase in [Wikipedia:SQS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Simple_Queue_Service#Message_deletion) that it writes:

> Amazon reserves the right to delete an entire queue without notification if it has not been accessed for 30 consecutive days.

1. Is this confirmed? I can't find relevant resources though.
2. If that's the case, says, my program hasn't been calling SQS for quite awhile, does that mean I would need to **ensure** my queue is always there by calling `CreateQueue` whenever I want to push some messages to queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the queue does not exist, you will get the `AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue` error (see [SQS API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Query_QueryErrors.html)). So a safe way is to send without any additional checking, and handle errors appropriately.

That said, normally if you use a queue you have some receiving component polling the queue from time time (or all the time, using e.g. long polling). The presence of that component ensures that the queue exists; that is, on the receiving end you'd create the queue if it doesn't exist, and then just access it (according to the docs, each access counts).

And if there's no receiving component which checks the queue from time to time, there's no really much sense in sending messages :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to confirm the fact that they have reserved the right to delete queues which haven't been used in 30 days:

> Amazon SQS can delete your queue without notification if one of the
>   following actions hasn't been performed on it for 30 consecutive days:
>   SendMessage, ReceiveMessage, DeleteMessage, GetQueueAttributes,
>   SetQueueAttributes, AddPermission, and RemovePermission.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSConcepts.html#AboutQueues

Comment: Because our SQS dequeue is activated by a SNS, so we might run into this issue if we never get any requests. Thanks for this. We might need to implement a small snippet to create queue if queue was lost.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This warning has been replaced [in the current SQS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-how-it-works.html) with:

> Note
>
> Unless your application specifically requires repeatedly creating
>   queues and leaving them inactive or storing large amounts of data in
>   your queue, consider using Amazon S3 for storing your data.

Nothing about Amazon deleting them, so take it FWIW.